# Backbone fetch abruptly stopping without error or waring

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js, coffeescript, sinon

My project is setup with the [brunch-with-chapling](https://github.com/paulmillr/brunch-with-chaplin) boilerplate with some additional libraries:

- Sinon
- Chai
- Mocha
- PapaParse
- StringView

The problem I am having is when i am trying to fetch a model my fake server shows that i have successfully received and replied to a request that has been made. Jet the success nor error function is triggered.

This is my code for fetching:

Base (Shop) class:

```
###
# Appends header to fetch request.
###
getModel: (id, obj)->
  console.log "Requesting model #{@type} with id #{id}", 'model'
  obj.url = "#{@urlRoot()}/#{id}"
  @fetch obj

###
# Fetches models.
###
fetch: (options = {})=>
  console.log options
  options.headers ?= {}
  options.headers.Authorization = Mediator.execute 'getAuth'
  options.headers.Accept = 'application/json;charset=utf-8'

  success = options.success
  options.success = ->
    console.log 'test'
    success()

  options.error = ->
    console.log 'error'

  super options
```

View class

```
initialize: (options = {})->

  shopId = Mediator.execute 'getActiveShop'

  if shopId is undefined
    setTimeout (=>@initialize()), 50
    return

  @shop = new Shop
  console.log @shop
  @shop.accountId = (Mediator.execute 'getAccount').get 'id'
  @shop.getModel shopId, {
    success: =>
      console.log 'test'
      @render()
    error: ((a,b,c)=> @publishEvent 'modelConnectionError', a,b,c)
  }
  super
```

Comment: did you try to see what you get by listening to `request`,`sync`,`error` event? and can you share `model.sync` if you modify something?

Comment: I have accutally fixed it by replacing fetch with a ajax normal request, and no i have not modified model.sync